# unicode text to Japanese text for Rakuten Web service API

Tags: python, api, unicode

Hi I'm using Rakuten Web service API to play around with it in Ipython Notebook. I successfully loaded the product ranking data using this url (https://app.rakuten.co.jp/services/api/IchibaItem/Ranking/20120927?format=json&applicationId=1074393356181806125)

My question is that since the Japanese text is unicode, I cannot read the text. How can I handle this?

Here is my code on Ipython Notebook:

```
import requests
import urllib2
url = 'https://app.rakuten.co.jp/services/api/IchibaItem/Ranking/20120927?format=json&page=1&applicationId=1074393356181806125'
r = requests.get(url)
res = r.json()
res['title']
```

Current output for title for example:

```
u'\u3010\u697d\u5929\u5e02\u5834\u3011\u30e9\u30f3\u30ad\u30f3\u30b0\u5e02\u5834 \u3010\u7dcf\u5408\u3011'
```

When I code `print(res['title'])`, I got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please someone help?

Comment: encode it to utf8 or something default in sys.filesystemencoding() to print to console

Comment: I tried .encode('utf8) and same for ascii but it doesn't give me the string. utf gives me this. '\xe3\x80\x90\xe6\xa5\xbd\xe5\xa4\xa9\xe5\xb8\x82\xe5\xa0\xb4\xe3\x80\x91\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xad\xe3\x83\xb3\xe3\x82\xb0\xe5\xb8\x82\xe5\xa0\xb4 \xe3\x80\x90\xe7\xb7\x8f\xe5\x90\x88\xe3\x80\x91' And ascii gives me the same error as above

Comment: what encoding is your shell? sys.getfilesystemencoding()

Comment: What OS and Python version? It works for me on Windows 7 64-bit with Python 3.3.5 in IPython Notebook: `'【楽天市場】ランキング市場 【総合】'`. Running at command line, however, gives `'\u3010\u697d...'` because US Windows-localized console doesn't support Japanese without help.

Comment: sys.getfilesystemencoding() gives me utf-8.

Comment: I'm using OSX El Captain and Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I wonder why your Ipython notebooks gives the correct string and mine doesn't :(

Comment: Okay, I decided to use python3! Thanks :)

Comment: Is your terminal configured with the environment variable `LC_TYPE=en_US.UTF-8`?  IPython may not be detecting your terminal's encoding.

Answer (score 0):

That is the representation of an Unicode string, see [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=repr#repr).

Just *print* the actual text instead of showing the representation:

```
print(res['title'])
```

Printing Unicode is tricky however, Eg. for Windows see [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console).

Comment: Thanks, roeland, I tried but I still get the error which I added in the question. Could you help me out?

Comment: Well that's an entirely different question. For lpython I have no idea, better ask or search for a question handling that.